# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onchange' of null Javascript

Tags: javascript

Trying to code a simple equalizer in JS where user controllers the maxRadius with a slider but i keep getting this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onchange' of null.

Here is my function:

maxRadius is a global variable declared.

```
 document.querySelector("#slider1").onchange = function(e) {
   console.log("value=" + e.target.value);
   document.querySelector("#sliderResults").innerHTML = e.target.value;
   maxRadius = e.target.value * 500;
 };
```

and here is my html

```
<div>
  <label for="slider1">Circle Size</label>
  <input id="slider1" type="range" min="0.1" max="1.0" step="0.1" value="0.5" />
  <span style="float:right" id="sliderResults"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Make sure the DOM is ready before you access it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Answer (score 0):

You just to make sure that document is ready

Try like this

```
function fn() {

  document.querySelector("#slider1").onchange = function(e) {
    console.log("value=" + e.target.value);
    document.querySelector("#sliderResults").innerHTML = e.target.value;
    maxRadius = e.target.value * 500;
  };

}

document.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
    fn();
  }
};
```

```js
function fn() {

  document.querySelector("#slider1").onchange = function(e) {
    console.log("value=" + e.target.value);
    document.querySelector("#sliderResults").innerHTML = e.target.value;
    maxRadius = e.target.value * 500;
  };

}

document.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
    fn();
  }
};
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="slider1">Circle Size</label>
  <input id="slider1" type="range" min="0.1" max="1.0" step="0.1" value="0.5" />
  <span style="float:right" id="sliderResults"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
document.getElementById("slider1").onchange = function(e)
        {
            console.log("value=" + e.target.value);
            document.querySelector("#sliderResults").innerHTML = e.target.value;
            maxRadius = e.target.value * 500;
        };
```